# Why in Laravel 5 app emails sent using laravel-mail-preview plugin are not received by receivers?

Tags: templates, laravel-5, ssmtp

In view of 5.7 laravel app I use themsaid/laravel-mail-preview plugin for testing of emails sending with snowfire/beautymail templates
and for this in .env of my local project I have options:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=preview
# MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

that works ok and into "/storage/email-previews" subdirectory of my local system generated emails are copied.

But moving to my server app (ubuntu 18 under Digital ocean) I have a problem that emails are sent and receivers do not receive it.
On my server I have installed ssmtp  and in file /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf I added creditials of my gmail account and when I send testing email 
with        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) function receivers receive these emails ok

But why I do not receive emails witch are sent with snowfire/beautymail templates ?

In .env of my server app:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
# MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_USERNAME=gmailnick@gmail.com   # the same parameters I have in /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX      # my gmail factor authentication password

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

In logs I see

```
# grep -riI ssmtp /var/log

/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  5 23:34:06 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[3432]: Sent mail for root@smtp.gmail.com:587 (221 2.0.0 closing connection w18-v6sm13037750wrn.66 - gsmtp) uid=0 username=root outbytes=860
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 00:34:06 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[4242]: Creating SSL connection to host
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 00:34:06 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[4242]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 00:34:08 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[4242]: Sent mail for root@smtp.gmail.com:587 (221 2.0.0 closing connection b71-v6sm476787wma.13 - gsmtp) uid=0 username=root outbytes=860
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 01:34:07 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[5342]: Creating SSL connection to host
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 01:34:07 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[5342]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 01:34:09 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[5342]: Sent mail for root@smtp.gmail.com:587 (221 2.0.0 closing connection c24-v6sm77924472wre.44 - gsmtp) uid=0 username=root outbytes=860
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 02:34:07 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[6155]: Creating SSL connection to host
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 02:34:07 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[6155]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 02:34:08 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[6155]: Sent mail for root@smtp.gmail.com:587 (221 2.0.0 closing connection m13-v6sm6126322wrw.14 - gsmtp) uid=0 username=root outbytes=860
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 03:34:07 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[7181]: Creating SSL connection to host
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 03:34:08 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[7181]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 03:34:09 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[7181]: Sent mail for root@smtp.gmail.com:587 (221 2.0.0 closing connection t13-v6sm26521034wrn.22 - gsmtp) uid=0 username=root outbytes=860
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 04:34:04 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[7905]: Creating SSL connection to host
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 04:34:04 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[7905]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 04:34:06 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[7905]: Sent mail for root@smtp.gmail.com:587 (221 2.0.0 closing connection v11-v6sm12069528wrt.40 - gsmtp) uid=0 username=root outbytes=860
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 05:34:05 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[8799]: Creating SSL connection to host
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 05:34:05 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[8799]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov  6 05:34:07 nsn-do-lamp sSMTP[8799]: Sent mail for root@smtp.gmail.com:587 (221 2.0.0 closing connection g16-v6sm20220322wrr.38 - gsmtp) uid=0 username=root outbytes=860
```

I have cron set at my server and message above looks like from this cron sending emails...

is it issue of my server's .env file?
What can be wrong ?

MODIFIED BLOCK # 2:
I modified .env of my app:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_USERNAME=gmailnick@gmail.com   # the same parameters I have in /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX      # my gmail factor authentication password

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

and cleared the cache
But sending email I got error :

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. r1-v6sm13862441wrt.59 - gsmtp "
```

What is wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to set MAIL_HOST as smtp.gmail.com

Comment: Thank you for feedback!
Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 2

Comment: Change MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls and try once.